# Do minified class names change and if so how often?

Tags: javascript, css, webkit, minify, bundling-and-minification

I'm trying to create a custom user-defined CSS stylesheet to modify my Reddit experience on Reddit. In doing so I've found that many class names have been hashed to arbitrary strings to prevent conflicts across the site.

So with that said, If my user-defined styles use the hashed class/id names are they likely to change on me with updates to the site's codebase?

If yes, vaguely how often would they change? With every update or only when that section of the site is updated?

Comment: There are many different minifiers, it depends on what they're using. I wouldn't expect it to be consistent.

Comment: I don't think there can be a definitive answer to this. Other than 'are they likely to change': quite possibly, and 'how often';: it may happen at times that are out of your control so nothing you can do about it'.

Comment: Some bigger sites also intentionally use this as a mechanism to make it harder to scrape content, so they might change frequently.